# Как убрать все html теги из строки

Tags: java, android, строки

Как удалить все html теги из строки?

Вот у меня `String` имеет такой вид `"<  font color=red>TRRRR < font color=#00F>"`
А мне нужно чтобы строчка имела такой вид `"TRRRRR"`

Спасибо...

Comment: Подозреваю, что HTML-парсером. Известно по крайней мере, что регулярные выражения плохо справляются с синтаксическим анализом HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для не сильно сложной разметки можно так:

```
String plain = Html.fromHtml(htmlString).toString();
```

Comment: Для сложной мне кажется тоже можно, просто он не все теги знает, но те которые не знает, игнорирует. А те которые знает, конвертирует в span для spanable.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Точто надо!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант воспользоваться библиотекой [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) для распарсивания HTML - документов